# Swapping two Array elements in a Struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I can post the whole code if you guys want, but here is the essence of my problem:

```
typedef struct
{
    CardT cards[DECK_SIZE];
    int count;
}DeckT;

void shuffleDeck(DeckT *deck){
   int k=50;
   DeckT *randCard = deck;
   DeckT *startCard = deck;

   while (k>0){
    int r = k % 25;
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i < r; i++, randCard++){
            printf("%i %i",i,r);
    }

    CardT A;    //do I declare A to be a Card Struc or a pointer to the array of cards?
    A = *randCard;                     //this is where my program locks up.
    *randCard = *startCard;            //swapping pointers seems pointless [hehe]
    *startCard = A;       

    printf(" yo yo yo shuffle\n");   //doesn't print this line at all, locks up before
    k--;
    *startCard++;
    }
```

I understand that I need to swap the actual elements and not the pointers, but I am unsure how to do it.  Basic flow of the function is to declar two pointers to my deck, which point to the array of cards [ do i need to specify this?] then swap cards based on the k%25.

I'm not to worried about the actual randomness of the swapping right now, i just want to know how to swap two cards[which are themselves structs].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
DeckT *startCard
```

should be

```
CardT *startCard = &deck->cards[0];
```

Ditto for `randCard` but this variable can/should be moved in the inner loop

Answer (score 0):

You got confused about which pointers to use.  `Deck*` points to a deck structure.  If you add 1 to it, it will point to a `Deck` immediately following the first one (as if you had an array of decks).  I'm pretty sure you didn't mean that.

You want to operate on `CardT`.  There's no need to use the pointers.  If you have two indices to swap, let's say `i` and `j`, just operate directly on the `cards` array:

```
CardT temp = deck->cards[i];
deck->cards[i] = deck->cards[j];
deck->cards[j] = temp;
```